# Strongly typed global data in ASP.Net Web Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

What's best practice to store strongly typed global data in ASP.Net Web Pages, which is unique for each request? Basically I need `WebPageContext.Current.PageData` but strongly typed.

Until now I came up with something like this:

```
public sealed class GlobalData
{
    public static GlobalData Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (WebPageContext.Current.PageData["GlobalData"] == null
                || WebPageContext.Current.PageData["GlobalData"].GetType() != typeof(GlobalData))
            {
                WebPageContext.Current.PageData["GlobalData"] = new GlobalData();
            }
            return WebPageContext.Current.PageData["GlobalData"];
        }
    }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

This way I could simply access my data with `GlobalData.Current.SomeData` on every pages. Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty good approach. I'd simplify it a bit:

```
public sealed class GlobalData
{
    public static GlobalData Current
    {
        get
        {
            // soft cast using "as" which will return null if the type is not correct
            var globalData = WebPageContext.Current.PageData["GlobalData"] as GlobalData;
            if (globalData == null)
            {
                // Need to instantiate
                globalData = new GlobalData();
                WebPageContext.Current.PageData["GlobalData"] = globalData;
            }

            return globalData;
        }
    }

    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Since I'd like to keep things simple and short,  do you think there's a way to get rid of this static `Current` property? I would prefer to just access my data with `GlobalData.SomeData`. That would probably work with a static constructor but then it wouldn't create a new GlobalData for each request, right?

Comment: You can't make GlobalData static because then all users will share one copy. Since you want a copy per user, the static Current property effectively implements a quasi-singleton that is one per Request. If I were you, the only change I'd make is to use HttpContext.Current.Items, which is a "cache" that lives for the request lifecycle, if it's available to you.

Comment: Thank you for the tip about the "as" operator, very useful for keeping code clean when there might be a null.